# ¿Cómo ordenar barras de forma decreciente usando facet_wrap en ggplot? R

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

Tengo una duda, cómo se puede ordenar las barras usando `facet_wrap()`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

iris %>% gather(medida, valor, -Species) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(reorder(Species, valor), valor, fill=reorder(Species, valor))) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~ medida, scales = "free")+
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se puede ver que las barras del último grupo no están ordenadas.
¿Cómo se podría ordenarlos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay una solución para ese problema en la librería `tidytext`. Es un poco raro que esté en una librería de procesamiento de lenguaje natural y no en una extensión de `ggplot2`, ocurre que es un problema recurrente cuando se grafican conteos de palabras.

Se trata de dos funciones que trabajan juntas: `reorder_within()` que permite hacer reordenamientos por más de una variable y `scale_x_reordered()` que es un escala para `ggplot2` que entiende esos reordenamientos.

Tu caso está cubierto en la ayuda de `scale_x_reordered()`, solamente lo estoy adaptando, no he cambiado ni los nombres.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)
iris_gathered <- gather(iris, metric, value, -Species)

ggplot(iris_gathered, aes(reorder_within(Species, value, metric), value, fill = Species)) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_x_reordered() +
  facet_wrap(~ metric, scales = "free_x")
```

El resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema se produce porque reorder genera un factor ordenado se `Species`, pero lo ordena de mayor a menor en general, es decir, dentro de todos los grupos. Entonces `virginica` que tiene el valor más alto entre todos los grupos se considera mayor y se pierde la información de que en el grupo `Sepal.Width` el valor más alto lo tiene `setosa`.

La solución de `tidytext` es ordenar grupos con las dos variables. Puedes ver el comportamiento usando la función dentro de un `mutate` antes de graficar en lugar de hacerlo directamente en la llamada de `ggplot`. Y `scale_x_reordered()` luego separa esa columna en dos y aplica en reordenamiento dentro de cada grupo. En realidad es un workaround no muy elegante, pero funciona...

Comment: Muchísimas gracias mpaladino.